# How to draw a native looking statusitem background on a CALayer

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, calayer, nsstatusitem, cgcolor

Actually I want to draw the background of a selected `NSStatusItem` on the `CALayer` of my custom statusItemView. But since

`- (void)drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:(NSRect)rect withHighlight:(BOOL)highlight`

does not work (?) on layers I've tried it to draw the color with the backgroundColor property. But converting the selectedMenuItemColor into RGB doesn't help very much. It looks really plain without the gradient. :-/

I converted `[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor]` into a `CGColorRef` with this code:

```
- (CGColorRef)highlightColor {
    static CGColorRef highlight = NULL;
    if(highlight == NULL) {
        CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
        NSColor *hlclr = [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] colorUsingColorSpace:
                     [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]];
        [hlclr getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
        CGFloat values[4] = {red, green, blue, alpha};
        highlight = CGColorCreate([self genericRGBSpace], values);
    }
    return highlight;
}
```

Any idea how to draw a native looking statusitem background on a CALayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try subclassing CALayer and implementing [the `drawInContext:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/drawInContext:) to [create an NSGraphicsContext for the CGContext](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [set the NSGraphicsContext as the current context](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and then tell the status item to draw its background.

Comment: This looks great. Do you know how to implement this? Thanks. Email me at http://j.mp/a2email. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSImage *backgroundImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size]];
[backgroundImage lockFocus];
[self.statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:self.bounds withHighlight:YES];
[backgroundImage unlockFocus];
[self.layer setContents:backgroundImage];
[backgroundImage release];
```

Comment: This option is easier than subclassing CALayer as offered above.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my layer delegate:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer 
        inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    NSGraphicsContext* gc = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:context flipped:NO];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:gc];
    [self.statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:self.frame 
                                     withHighlight:self.isHighlighted];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```